# I can not process RetrofitError message

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit library. If I am not connected to internet, `retrofit` show message

> failed to connect to /192.168.0.*** (port 8082): connect failed:
>   ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

it's good but I haven't error code from `RetrofitError error`. Can i process this message and replace for my message?

RetrofitError error has method `getMeassage()` and has not `getCode()`

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can handle the Retrofit Error. You can customize the message for your application. To handle the Retrofit error you can implements the  interface retrofit ErrorHandler. For example see below steps.

Steps 1. Create the class that extends the Exception class, This class handle the exception throw from ErrorHandler. We will see the class in next steps.

```
public class AdvanceException extends Exception {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String message = null;

    public RelaxisException() {
        super();
    }

    public RelaxisException(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
    }

    public RelaxisException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Steps 2. Create another class that extends ErrorHandler. We used the RestAdapter build **setErrorHandler** properties for register this class, so that when the retrofit throw an exception this class will handle the error.

```
public class RetrofitErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        if (retrofitError.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
            return new AdvanceException(RApplication.getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_no_internet_available));
        } else if (retrofitError.getCause() instanceof java.net.SocketTimeoutException) {
            return new AdvanceException(RApplication.getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_server_not_rechable));
        } else if (retrofitError.getCause() instanceof java.net.UnknownHostException) {
            return new AdvanceException(RApplication.getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_server_not_available));
        } else {
            return new AdvanceException(RApplication.getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_internal_problem));
        }
    }

}
```

Steps 3. Below is the RestAdapter Build where i did define the property for handler the error.

```
mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
.setEndpoint(HOST_SERVER)
.setErrorHandler(new RetrofitErrorHandler())
.build();
```

Let me know if you any questions try this i hope will help you, thank you.